# Correct initialization of state for properties without a setter in unit tests

Tags: c#, initialization, xunit, getter-setter

I have problems setting the correct state before unit testing. The simplified model below examplifies my problem. A `Student` entity has a property `Courses` of type `IReadOnlyCollection` and only a getter.

```
public class Course : ICourse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student : IStudent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Course> Courses { get; }
}
```

Before deletion of a `Student` the entity is eager loaded from a Repository and any `Course` the student is assigned to are also eager loaded (Using `Include`) into `Courses`.
`StudentService` must check if any `Course` exists before performing delete of `Student`

```
public class StudentService : IStudentService
{
    public async Task<bool> DeleteStudent(int id)
    {
        Student student = await myRepository.GetStudent(id);
        if !student.Courses.Any()

            await myRepository.DeleteStudent(id);

        throw Exception;
    }
}
```

To Unit test this functionality I have created the test below, but I cannot bring `Student` to the correct state as the Courses property has no setter.
I can of cause change the setter to public, but I don´t want the programmer to add `Courses` to a `Student`, `Student` shall  only be added to `Courses`. But this breaks encapsulation and is also considered bad pratice for unit testing.

```
public class StudentServiceTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void DeleteStudent_Success()
    {
        // Arrange
        Student student = new Student
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Test Name",
            Courses = new List<Course> { new Course { Id = 1 } }
        };

        Mock<IMyRepository> mockRepo = new Mock<IMyRepository>();
        mockRepo.Setup(repos => repos.GetStudent(It.Is<int>(i => i == 1).Result).Returns(student).Verifiable();
        mockRepo.Setup(repos => repos.DeleteStudent(It.Is<int>(i => i == 1).Result).Verifiable();

        IMyRepository studentRepos = mockRepo.Object;

        IStudentService studentService = new StudentService(studentRepos);

        // Act
        Func<Task> act = () => studentRepos.DeleteStudent(entry);

        // Assert
        act().Should().ThrowAsync<Exception>();
        mockRepo.Verify(repos => repos.GetStudent(It.Is<int>(i => i == 1), Times.Once);
        mockRepo.Verify(repos => repos.DeleteStudent(It.Is<int>(i => i == 1), Times.Never);
    }
}
```

Any good idea or hint on how to set the correct state of `Student`?

Comment: You could set the property via reflection

Comment: Is using reflection considered good or bad practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with an helper class using Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll.

```
    public class StudentAccessor
    {
        private readonly PrivateType privateType = new PrivateType(typeof(Student));
        private readonly PrivateObject privateObject;

        internal StudentAccessor(Student target)
        {
            privateObject = new PrivateObject(target, privateType);
        }

        internal IReadOnlyCollection<Course> Courses
        {
            get => (IReadOnlyCollection<Course>) privateObject.GetProperty("Courses");
            set => privateObject.SetField("courses", value);
        }

        //If you don't want to create a private field use this one
        internal IReadOnlyCollection<Course> Courses2
        {
            get => (IReadOnlyCollection<Course>) privateObject.GetProperty("Courses");
            set => privateObject.SetField("<Courses>k__BackingField", value);
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        private IReadOnlyCollection<Course> courses;

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IReadOnlyCollection<Course> Courses => courses;
    }
```